# Azure DevOps Test Plans - Synchronize JUnit test results in Runs with test cases on Tests Plan

Tags: azure, junit, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, is there any way that I can synchronize the results in Runs with test cases in Test Plans automatically?

My process is:

1. Release pipeline is set up to trigger Jenkins build to run automated tests.
2. JUnit test results will be downloaded and published once the build is completed.

Tasks in automation run stage of pipeline.

[image]

The process works as expected. I can see the JUnit results in Runs section as the image below. However, the outcome of the test results in Runs (all failed) is not synchronized with test cases in Test Plans (still be active). Can I have the outcome of test cases in Test Plans updated every time the automation build is run and then JUnit XML results are published to Runs?

Results in Test Runs.

[image]

Test cases in Test Plans.

[image]

So fat is there any settings of Azure DevOps to make it done automatically or I have to update the test outcome in Test Plans manually?

Comment: hello, you found any answer for this?